# Where is the black behind my navigation bar coming from?

Tags: flutter, dart

After rounding the corners of my navigation bar I noticed there's still something there. When I set the scaffolds background color to transparent, what's behind my navigation bar is black.. if I change it to blue, it's blue.. So is it the scaffold? How do I get it to show my home page behind it? I'm new at this...

```
class Navigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationState createState() => _NavigationState();
}

class _NavigationState extends State<Navigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
 Home(),
 Options(),
 Menu(),
  Search (),
  Text ('Profile')
];

void _onItemTap(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack (
        children: [_widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)],
      ),

        bottomNavigationBar:  Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color (0xFF213359),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),),),

          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              elevation: 0,


              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppHouse.sketch_house,
                     size: 27.5,), label: (''),),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppOptionsLong.sketch_options_long,
                    size: 35), label: (''),),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon((MyFlutterAppBook.sketch_book),
                  size: 34, ), label: (''),),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppSearch.sketch_search,
                     size: 34), label: (''),),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(MyFlutterAppPerson.sketch_person,
                  size: 30.5), label: (''),),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex, 
              onTap: _onItemTap,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
              selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );

}
}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962755/13840864

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is the scaffold once its transparent you see the material app which is black ,
one you put color back it appears , it is that simple.

and if you want to see your home page from the radius gap you can add extendBody property to your scaffold

```
extendBody: true,
```

Comment: Ah, so, how do I fix that? I want it to show what's behind, like my home page

Comment: I've Edited answer check it

Comment: also make your bottombar background same as scaffold and home .. if method above not working